# Ring of even characteristic.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Is possible to choose three units $u,v,w$ of a ring $R$ (not containing a field) with even characteristic 
such that $u+v+w=0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, take $R = \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ or any field of characteristic $2$ with more than 2 elements.  Choose a nonzero element $u$, another nonzero element $v$ such that $u + v \neq 0$ and then set $w = u + v = -(u + v)$ because we are characteristic $2$.  

Comment: I thought about it, i will add "not a field" in the question.
Because im interested in the units on the ring and in a field this is not a interesting concept.
But thanks anyway for the comment.


Comment: Adding "not a field" to the question hardly matters.  Replace Karl's $R$ with the polynomial ring $R[X]$, but keep Karl's $u,v,w$ unchanged (in $R$).

Comment: Perhaps you want, "does not contain a field"?

Comment: @Karl Schwede 
Yeah, it looks like if it contains a field then the result is trivial and the answer is yes.
I will try to think in a ring not containing a field that have this property, if the answer is trivial i will delete the post.
Thanks for the observations.

Comment: Karl, what could characteristic $2$ mean then?

Comment: "Even characteristic" could be $4$.

Comment: I think there are such examples of rings not containing a field with this property.    For example:

$$(\mathbb{Z}/4)[x,x^{-1},(x+1)^{-1}].$$

Then setting $u = x$, $v = x^2$ and hence $w = 3x+3x^2 = 3x(1+x)$ should do the trick.

I can see why you might ask this though.  In $\mathbb{Z}/(2n)$, units are always odd, so the sum of three of them is also odd and hence still odd modulo $2n$.  However, I expect that there are even a number of easy examples that are finite extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/(2n)$.  